# observing contentSize (CGSize) with KVO in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, key-value-observing

I'm trying to observering `collectionView.contentSize` like this :

```
func startObserveCollectionView() {
    collectionView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old.union(NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New), context: &SearchDasboardLabelContext)
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if context == &SearchDasboardLabelContext {       
        if object === collectionView && keyPath! == "contentSize" {
            print(change)               
        }
    }
}
```

and in  xcode terminal I got a `NSSize` not `CGSize` like this :

```
Optional(["old": NSSize: {320, 0}, "new": NSSize: {375, 39.5}, "kind": 1])
```

In objective-c I used method `CGSizeValue`

```
CGSize newContentSize = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] CGSizeValue];
```

Is there any method like `CGSizeValue` in swift

I have tried in swift `var newContentSize = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]?.CGSizeValue()` but got error

> could not find member 'CGSizeValue'

need help anyone? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you on iOS? Because I am, I did the same thing and arrived at the same question; why `NSSize`? Maybe that's just the xcode terminal playing a trick on us.

Anyway, you can cast it to an `NSValue` then you will be able to use `CGSizeValue`:

```
if let zeChange = change as? [NSString: NSValue] {
    let oldSize = zeChange[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey]?.CGSizeValue()
    let newSize = zeChange[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]?.CGSizeValue()
}
```

Answer (score 14):

With Swift 4, you can cast the result of the `change` dictionary for the key `NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey` as being of type `CGSize`:

```
if let size = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? CGSize {
    /* ... */
}
```

---

The following `UIViewController` implementation shows how to set a KVO stack in order to observe the changes of the `contentSize` property of any `UIScrollView` subclass (e.g `UITextView`):

```
import UIKit

private var myContext = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    /* ... */

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(UITextView.contentSize), options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new], context: &myContext)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if context == &myContext,
            keyPath == #keyPath(UITextView.contentSize),
            let contentSize = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? CGSize {
            print("contentSize:", contentSize)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        textView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(UITextView.contentSize))
    }

}
```

---

Note that with Swift 4, as an alternative to `addObserver(_:, forKeyPath:, options:, context:)` and `observeValue(forKeyPath:, of:, change:, context:)`, you can use `observe(_:, options:, changeHandler:)` in order to track your `UIScrollView` subclass `contentSize` property changes:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

    /* ... */

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let handler = { (textView: UITextView, change: NSKeyValueObservedChange<CGSize>) in
            if let contentSize = change.newValue {
                print("contentSize:", contentSize)
            }
        }
        observer = textView.observe(\UITextView.contentSize, options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new], changeHandler: handler)
    }

}
```

Comment: Regarding the Swift 4 code:  is this supposed to get called when the scrollview scrolls? I am getting multiple successive outputs with the same contentSize every time I scroll.  I would think this should only trigger if the actual contentSize changes

Comment: What for is the "\" in `... observe(\UITextView.contentSize ...`?

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler and arguably swiftier alternative.

You can subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` (or any of its subclasses, like `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`) and override a computed property `collectionViewContentSize`. By calling `super` you'll get the contentSize of your collection and be able to delegate this value back to your code.

So you'll have something like this:

```
protocol FlowLayoutDelegate: class {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView?, didChange contentSize: CGSize)
}

class FlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    weak var delegate: FlowLayoutDelegate?

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        let contentSize = super.collectionViewContentSize
        delegate?.collectionView(collectionView, didChange: contentSize)
        return contentSize
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example code:

```
if context == ApprovalObservingContext{
        if let theChange = change as? [NSString: Bool]{

            var newContentSize = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]?.CGSizeValue()
        }
    }
```

This is not giving any error.