# UICollectionView wrapper view frame update

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view wrap by UIView, the collection view has same bounds with wrapper view. And collection view data source will be changed, so the wrapper view bounds also be changed. I have implement the wrapper view `intrinsicContentSize` method with `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize`, and the collection view layout is subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, the cell of the UICollectionView has also implement method `intrinsicContentSize`, but the wrapper view did not update frame with collection view content size. `collectionViewContentSize` is always `CGRectZero`.
I have tried

```
  [self.layout invalidateLayout];
  [self.collectionView reloadData];
  [self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
```

but did not work,
 What should I do to update the wrapper view frame with `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize`.

There is some code below:

```
  ZXCollectionViewWrapperView *wrapperView = [[ZXCollectionViewWrapperView alloc] init];
  [self.view addSubview:wrapperView];
  [wrapperView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.center.equalTo(self.view);
  }];
  self.wrapperView = wrapperView;

   /// wrapper view size 
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
  return self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize;
}


  ZXCollectionViewAlignedLayout *layout = [[ZXCollectionViewAlignedLayout alloc] init];
  self.layout = layout;
  ZXCollectionView *collectionView = [[ZXCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
  collectionView.dataSource = self;
  collectionView.delegate = self;
  collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
  [self addSubview:collectionView];
  [collectionView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(self);
  }];
  self.collectionView = collectionView;

  [self.collectionView zx_registerCellClass:[ZXCommendCell class]];

  self.dataSource = dataSource;
  [self.collectionView reloadData];
  [self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using autolayout, you should create a height constraint for wrapper view. Then you can change the constant of that constraint to equal collection view content size, like this:

```
heightConstraint = make.height.equalTo(200) // initial height
```

then you can use KVO to observe collection view content size to change and set

```
heightConstraint.constant = collectionView.contentSize.height
```

you can refer to this for observing contentSize: [observing contentSize (CGSize) with KVO in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421387/observing-contentsize-cgsize-with-kvo-in-swift)

Comment: I want the wrapper view adjust size by UICollectionView contentSize, like UILabel with wrapper view.(UIlLabel with wrapper view did work, I have tried).

Comment: you cannot do that with collection view as it is a scroll view